# React - show photo if media type is a photo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use a loop in jsx which is working.

I am making a call to an API which returns a list of instagram posts. This works fine, however some posts have both videos and photos linked to them, which is causing the issue.

If the post media type is a `video` then the `type === 'video'` else it is `type === 'photo'`. I have written this logic below, and when I `console.log(photo)` I get a link to the url of each photo, however, `<img src={photo} />` doesn't show the photo on the page, but instead shows `}` where the photo should be.

Can anyone advise me how I can fix this issue? Let me know if any further information is required. As far as i am aware it is because `photo` in the map function is in a different scope?

```
render: function() {
   var photo;
   var instagramPostList = this.props.posts.map(function(post, index){
     return(
        <li key={index} className='card'>
           <div className='insta-pic'>  
             {
               post.media.map(function(photo, index){
                  if(photo.type === 'photo') {
                     photo = post.media[index].url;
                        console.log(photo);
                   }
                })
              }
              <img src={photo} />
            }
           </div>
        </li>
    )
   })
   return (
      <div>
         <ul>{instagramPostList}</ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

In an attempt to access `photo` outside the `map` function I have tried add `this` which was also unsuccessful.

```
post.media.map(function(photo, index){
    if(photo.type === 'photo') {
        photo = post.media[index].url;
        console.log(photo)
    }
}, this);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
{
  post.media.map(function(photo, index){
    return photo.type === 'photo' && (<img src={photo.url} />)
  })
}
```

inside your

```
<div className='insta-pic'>  

</div>
```

You are using one extra `}` and your `<img src={photo.url} />` is out of the `.map` iterator.